# Create a CSV file in perl

Tags: perl, csv

Hey guys i've got script that takes 9 strings from a column.
And then i have to save them in a new CSV file and in csv format.
i've already tried Class::CSV but because i'm new to perl i failed to pass in the strings becouse theirs some data altering that happens before i save them in those strings.

So i hope you can give me an example to get started.

```
  my $csv = Class::CSV->new(
  fields         => [voornaam/achternaam],
  line_separator => "\r\n";
     );


 $csv->add_line({
        userid   => $voornaam,
        username => $achternaam


});
```

I've also tried this and it failed to work :(

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

                 $csv->column_names('gebruikernaam','Voornaam','achternaam','Wachtwoord','Telefoongebruiker','Telefooncode','SMS','telefoonnummer1','telefoonnummer2','telefoonnummer3','groep');
                 open $fh, ">", "file.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
                 //...
                 $csv->print ($fh, [$gebruiker, $voorltr, $achternm, $password, $placeholder, $placeholder, $functioncode, $function, $SMS, $telefoon1, $telefoon2, $telefoon3, $groep]);
                 //...
                 close $fh or die "$!";
```

Comment: Class::CSV is probably not the module you want - it uses Text::CSV and you should too. I'll do you an example in a minute.

Comment: You do not need a module to save things in csv format, if you do not want to. Just separating your fields with commas, semicolons, tabulators or whatever and saving the file as .csv does the work.

Comment: @DeVadder a module will handle escaping and quoting for you so I would advise using one

Comment: Certainly for bigger projects. Or at least those where you do not do stuff with the fields that the module did not expect. But i wanted to point out, that if all you need is a csv file containing a few simple fields, there is no need to wrap your head around a new module. Basic `print` and in extreme cases just a text editor can be enough. But it sure is valuable to learn Text::CSV and i would suggest doing it.

Comment: Define "failed to work." Did you get an error? If so, what was it? Was the file created, but empty? Did it not contain the right data? Something else completely different?

Comment: Loads of empty lines getting printed when i run the script.
Not a single error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Class::CSV but the synopsis at [metacpan Class::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aCSV) gives an example.

Specifically you need something like

```
 fields         => [ qw/voornaam achternaam/ ],
```

In a little more detail

- `qw/  /` creates an array words in the string you provide. So `qw/voornaam achternaam/` is equivalent to  `("voornaam", "achternaam" )`
- [  ] creates a reference to that array.